# Xbox Live leaderboard in UWP game returns with error 404

Tags: c++, uwp, xbox-live

When trying to retrieve a leaderboard from Xbox Live, the stat event type `get_leaderboard_complete` returns the error code 404. I'm using Xbox Live in a UWP game in the Creators Program.

I'm am able to set and retrieve the stat for the user. This part works without issue:

```
xbox_live_result<stat_value> serverStat = m_statsManager->get_stat(m_user, L"score");
auto result = serverStat.payload();
if (result.as_integer() < score) {
    setStatForUser(m_user, L"score", score);
}
```

My code is adopted from the leaderboard example in the [Xbox Live Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-samples). So to retrieve my leaderboard I'm calling `getLeaderboard(m_user, L"score");` and every frame I'm calling `statsManager->do_work();`.

```
// Process events from the stats manager
// This should be called each frame update

auto statsEvents = m_statsManager->do_work();
std::wstring text;

for (const auto& evt : statsEvents)
{
    switch (evt.event_type())
    {
    case stat_event_type::local_user_added:
        text = L"local_user_added";
        break;

    case stat_event_type::local_user_removed:
        text = L"local_user_removed";
        break;

    case stat_event_type::stat_update_complete:
        text = L"stat_update_complete";
        break;

    case stat_event_type::get_leaderboard_complete:
        text = L"get_leaderboard_complete";
        auto getLeaderboardCompleteArgs = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<leaderboard_result_event_args>(evt.event_args());
        processLeaderboards(evt.local_user(), getLeaderboardCompleteArgs->result());
        break;
    }

    stringstream_t source;
    source << _T("StatsManager event: ");
    source << text;
    source << _T(".");
    log("%S", source.str().c_str());
}
```

Because I'm able to set and retrieve the stat without issue, I wonder if maybe it's an issue with the Xbox Live backend? However, I'm not very familiar with the xbox live 2017 data platform, and I may be calling something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution:

1. Create a new stat/leaderboard in Dev Center.
2. Press the “Test” button. This is important because it publishes the service configuration.

I’m unsure why the original stat didn’t work. Perhaps because I used the word “score” as the statID.

Comment: I still get the 404 error, even though I have published the Leaderboard to the store? There is literally no help anywhere to help solve this. Yes even doing a "Test" publish doesn't help. While the user signs in perfectly and I get a GetLeaderboardComplete message after DoWork(), But any attempt to retrieve rows, returns the 404 error :(